# Is there a way to checkt the state of a window (whether its open or closed) in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to know whether it is possible to check if a window is closed or open like so:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
print(# The root's state.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `winfo_viewable` to determine if the window is visible.

```
state = "viewable" if root.winfo_viewable() else "hidden"
```

This will work for any widget, not just the root window. This is what the official documentation says:

> Returns 1 if window and all of its ancestors up through the nearest toplevel window are mapped. Returns 0 if any of these windows are not mapped.